# Why does pvremove have a duplicate "force" in the man page?

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

```
> man pvremove
PVREMOVE(8)            System Manager's Manual           PVREMOVE(8)

NAME
       pvremove — remove a physical volume

SYNOPSIS
       pvremove    [--commandprofile    ProfileName]    [-d|--debug]
       [-h|--help]    [-t|--test]     [-v|--verbose]     [--version]
       [-f[f]|--force   [--force]]   [--reportformat   {basic|json}]
       [-y|--yes] PhysicalVolume [PhysicalVolume...]

DESCRIPTION
       pvremove wipes the label on a device  so  that  LVM  will  no
       longer recognise it as a physical volume.

OPTIONS
       See lvm(8) for common options.

       -ff, --force --force
          Force the removal of a physical volume belonging to an
          existing volume group.  Normally vgreduce(8) should be
          used  instead  of  this  command.  You cannot remove a
          physical volume which in use by  some  active  logical
          volume.

       -y, --yes
          Answer yes to all questions.

SEE ALSO
       lvm(8), pvcreate(8), pvdisplay(8), vgreduce(8)

Sistina SoftwaLVMUTOOLS 2.02.166(2)-RHEL7 (2016-09-28)   PVREMOVE(8)
```

**Q:** Why the two "f"s?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a safety switch, kind of like the `--please-destroy-my-drive` option in `hdparm`. By default the program will refuse to do such a thing (as it will likely result in something broken) but it has an option to override, for people who really really really know what they are doing (at least, in their imagination).

Explanation as provided by the program itself (in addition to the manpage you already quoted)

```
# pvremove /dev/loop0
  PV /dev/loop0 is used by VG foobar so please use vgreduce first.
  (If you are certain you need pvremove, then confirm by using --force twice.)

# pvremove --force /dev/loop0
  PV /dev/loop0 is used by VG foobar so please use vgreduce first.
  (If you are certain you need pvremove, then confirm by using --force twice.)

# pvremove --force --force /dev/loop0
  WARNING: PV /dev/loop0 is used by VG foobar
Really WIPE LABELS from physical volume 
    "/dev/loop0" of volume group "foobar" [y/n]? y
  WARNING: Wiping physical volume label from /dev/loop0 of volume group "foobar"
  Labels on physical volume "/dev/loop0" successfully wiped.
```

It really doesn't want to do it and even asks for confirmation after using `-ff` (if ran in interactive mode).

As to why `--force` twice, wouldn't once be enough? LVM uses `--force` in other places for slightly less critical actions, so it's probably to catch people who are already in the habit of using a single `--force` with other LVM commands.

Answer (score 6):

The second `f` and `--force` are optional:

```
pvremove -f
```

is not the same as

```
pvremove -ff
```

(and the respective equivalents `pvremove --force` and `pvremove --force --force`).

Error handling differs depending on the number of `--force` options. For example, by default `pvremove` won't remove a volume which isn't already a PV; a single `--force` is sufficient to disable that check. A single `--force` also disables prompting (for basic cases). Removing a PV which is actually in use requires two `--force` options.